# Class constructor not initializing attributes when parameters have same name

Tags: c++, oop, parameters, constructor

I know that C++ allows for the parameters of a constructor to have the same names as the class attributes, but my attributes only initialize when the parameters have different names.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{
    int age;
    string name;

    public:
        Test(string name, int age){
            name=name;
            age=age;
        }
        
        void introduce(){
            cout << "My name is " << name << ". I am " << age << " years old." << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    Test bob("Bob", 53);
    bob.introduce();
}
```

Produces the output:

```
My name is . I am 6422476 years old.
```

But if I change the parameter names to some aliases like this:

```
Test(string nm, int ag){
    name=nm;
    age=ag;
}
```

Then the output is:

```
My name is Bob. I am 53 years old.
```

What went wrong here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Something else to chew on: What if I told you that `name=name;` isn't initialization, but instead an assignment?

Comment: This is a good example of why you should give members different names than parameters.  One coding style is to prefix members with "m_".  Another coding style is to append member names with"_".  This coding style makes your code easier to read and reduces confusion between parameters and members.

Comment: You could also use an initialization list:  `Test(const std::string& name, int age) : name(name), age(age) { }`  I still prefer using different names or employing a naming convention.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Still a bit confused as to why this doesn't work, considering everywhere else on SO says it's allowed. Regardless, I appreciate the feedback. Definitely a good practice to name them differently.

Comment: @AlanN: There are a whole bunch of stuff that is allowed in the C++, but it doesn't mean that it makes a good, readable, program.  For example: [The International Obfuscated C Code Contest](https://www.ioccc.org/)